# Why aren't my divs lining up?

Tags: html, css

The divs are lining up perfectly on my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Abijah/pv88G/), but they're not working on my [website](http://www.buymaengdakratom.com/).

I believe the problem is stemming from my contact form, because when I move my contact form below the two divs they lineup correctly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't clearing the floats within your `<div class="form">` element.

Two good solutions for your problem would be to either add `overflow: hidden` to `.form` or add `clear: both` to `#text`.

Comment: I really appreciate it.  Thanks, Wex.

Answer (score 0):

It works on jsFiddle because of their reset CSS :

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

In your case it is because of the h2 which has a bigger height than the rest of the line. It lead to the fact that your blue div starts at the end of the h2.

That should do the trick :

```
.form h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CFCFCF;
  color: #999;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

PS: the answer of @Wex is cleaner ;)

Comment: Tibo, thanks for the input.  It helped me understand why this was happening.